# having an issue at loading a library java

Tags: java, netbeans

I found a good library that is absolutely needed for my project, but I failed to implement it.

> https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent

I download the .zip file and in the library section of netbeans I selected the option "Add JAR/Folder". When I add the library folder to the library section, java does not let me import it to the .java file that I'm working on. I mean, java is not "recognising" the library. I also see this library is different from others that I had previously seen.

For example, I tried to implement "jsoup.jar" before and I did the same steps and it worked. I don't know why does these library isn't working.

If I'm not clear enough at this point, see the image below:
[image: mistake underlined in red: "package com.blablabla does not exist"]

I would want to know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you got a source bundle. They appear to be in [this maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.turn/ttorrent/1.4) repo. You could use maven to manage the dependency or you can grab the binary build [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.turn/ttorrent).